# How to revert an update on single mongo db document

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

I just updated a single document on mongo and my transaction wrong and i lost the previous data. Is there any way to get the data before making the update?

Comment: Atlas point in time restore.

Comment: @D.SM I am not using atlas right now, Do you think there is any other option to track the last updated data

Answer (score 1):

If you have written the document you are trying to restore recently, and you are using a replica set, you should be able to extricate the previous version of the document out of the oplog. Start [here](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-oplog/).

Atlas provides a point in time restore feature.

Comment: I am not using atlas, I host the databse my self on my server

Comment: Are you using replicaSet?